# How to save certain but also multiple words from a string into a variable?

Tags: python

If I have a string that is like this "Hello everyone Thank you for helping me"

Is there any python command that is easy to use that can generate a variable (lets say var) that contains the string "Hello Thank you for helping" based on the numbered order of the words? For example, I want to generate this string variable over multiple rows of a csv file all with the same format and for all of them, I hope to get a variable with the 1st, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th words of the string.

I know the split command, but im hoping to generate a variable with multiple words instead of printing just one.

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you hope to accomplish. Do you want a variable that holds everything except the second word..?

Comment: Edited the question, hope that clarifies things? But essentially yes, I want a variable that holds everything except the 2nd and 7th words

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
x="Hello everyone Thank you for helping me".split() 
del x[6] #throw away seventh word
del x[1] #throw away second word
s=" ".join(x)
```

?

Comment: And also join x back

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `split`, followed by a `list comprehension`, and finally a `join` like so:

```
>>> s = "Hello everyone Thank you for helping me"
>>> " ".join([x for i,x in enumerate(s.split()) if i not in (1,6)])
'Hello Thank you for helping'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based just on what you've provided, to get the, if existing, 1st/3rd/4th/5th/6th words all saved to one var and not a list, you would use

```
string1 = 'Hello everyone Thank you for helping me'
var = ' '.join([string1.split(' ')[i] for i in range(len(string1.split())) if i != 1 and i < 6])
```

I think you need to provide more details though, as this seems to be a very specific use case.